# converting html code to java script string format

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, response

I am having html code for hyperlink as below:

```
     <td> <a href="{% url 'select_stock_report' book.id %}">{{ book.code }}</a></td>
     <td>{{book.name}}</td>
```

it is directing to the correct page.

In Script from the response I update the page as below It is not giving error (of course link page is empty because of 1 as parameter):

```
html += "<tr> <td> <a href= '{% url 'select_stock_report' 1 %}'>"+item1.code+"</a></td>"+ 
  "<td>" + item1.name + "</td>" + "<td>" + item1.open_qty + " </td>"
```

But I want to replace 1 (one) with item1.id.

```
html += "<tr><td><a href='{% url 'select_stock_report' item1.id %}'>"+item1.code+"</a></td>"+
  "<td>" + item1.name + "</td>" + "<td>" + item1.open_qty + " </td>"
```

But I am getting error.

How to build the line with this replacement. I tried all "",'',+ with this item.id without success.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Exactly *what* is `item1`? A `Book` object?

Comment: yes it is book object ; item1.id =book.id;       item1.code=book.code

Comment: Can you share what error you get?

Comment: html += "<tr> <td> <a href= '{% url 'select_stock_report' item1.id 
   %}'>"+item1.code+"</a></td>"  +
 "<td>" + item1.name + "</td>" + "<td>" + item1.open_qty + " </td>"

Comment: Django Version: 3.1.1
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: 
Reverse for 'select_stock_report' with arguments '('',)' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['listselectstktrans/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', 'wstore/listselectstktrans/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']

Answer (score 0):

```
String content="<h1>Heading 1</h1>\n" +
             "        <h2>Heading 2</h2>\n" +
             "        <p>This is some html. Look, here\\'s an <u>underline</u>.</p>\n" +
             "        <p>Look, this is <em>emphasized.</em> And here\\'s some <b>bold</b>.</p>\n" +
             "        <p>Here are UL list items:\n" +
             "        <ul>\n" +
             "        <li>One</li>\n" +
             "        <li>Two</li>\n" +
             "        <li>Three</li>\n" +
             "        </ul>\n" +
             "        <p>Here are OL list items:\n" +
             "        <ol>\n" +
             "        <li>One</li>\n" +
             "        <li>Two</li>\n" +
             "        <li>Three</li>\n" +
             "        </ol>";
```

**Its use html inside of java**

Comment: While technically that's correct, this question is just not Java. "java script" in the title is just a misnomer for JavaScript, but the code is more likely Python anyway.